# Why Am I getting this "document is not defined" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a form like application in react native where users would be able to enter text and press a button and the the test the users entered would be emailed to me. I used EmailJS for this and my code is here below:

```
"use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var EmailJSResponseStatus_1 = require("./models/EmailJSResponseStatus");
    exports.EmailJSResponseStatus = EmailJSResponseStatus_1.EmailJSResponseStatus;
    var UI_1 = require("./services/ui/UI");
    var _userID = null;
    var _origin = 'https://api.emailjs.com';
    function sendPost(url, data, headers) {
        if (headers === void 0) { headers = {}; }
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                var responseStatus = new EmailJSResponseStatus_1.EmailJSResponseStatus(event.target);
                if (responseStatus.status === 200 || responseStatus.text === 'OK') {
                    resolve(responseStatus);
                }
                else {
                    reject(responseStatus);
                }
            });
            xhr.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
                reject(new EmailJSResponseStatus_1.EmailJSResponseStatus(event.target));
            });
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            for (var key in headers) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
            }
            xhr.send(data);
        });
    }
    function appendGoogleCaptcha(templatePrams) {
        var element = document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response');
        if (element && element.value) {
            templatePrams['g-recaptcha-response'] = element.value;
        }
        element = null;
        return templatePrams;
    }
    /**
     * Initiation
     * @param {string} userID - set the EmailJS user ID
     * @param {string} origin - set the EmailJS origin
     */
    function init(userID, origin) {
        _userID = userID;
        _origin = origin || 'https://api.emailjs.com';
    }
    exports.init = init;
    /**
     * Send a template to the specific EmailJS service
     * @param {string} serviceID - the EmailJS service ID
     * @param {string} templateID - the EmailJS template ID
     * @param {Object} templatePrams - the template params, what will be set to the EmailJS template
     * @param {string} userID - the EmailJS user ID
     * @returns {Promise<EmailJSResponseStatus>}
     */
    function send(serviceID, templateID, templatePrams, userID) {
        var params = {
            lib_version: '2.4.1',
            user_id: userID || _userID,
            service_id: serviceID,
            template_id: templateID,
            template_params: appendGoogleCaptcha(templatePrams)
        };
        return sendPost(_origin + '/api/v1.0/email/send', JSON.stringify(params), {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        });
    }
    exports.send = send;
    /**
     * Send a form the specific EmailJS service
     * @param {string} serviceID - the EmailJS service ID
     * @param {string} templateID - the EmailJS template ID
     * @param {string | HTMLFormElement} form - the form element or selector
     * @param {string} userID - the EmailJS user ID
     * @returns {Promise<EmailJSResponseStatus>}
     */
    function sendForm(serviceID, templateID, form, userID) {
        if (typeof form === 'string') {
            form = document.querySelector(form);
        }
        if (!form || form.nodeName !== 'FORM') {
            throw 'Expected the HTML form element or the style selector of form';
        }
        UI_1.UI.progressState(form);
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        formData.append('lib_version', '2.4.1');
        formData.append('service_id', serviceID);
        formData.append('template_id', templateID);
        formData.append('user_id', userID || _userID);
        return sendPost(_origin + '/api/v1.0/email/send-form', formData)
            .then(function (response) {
            UI_1.UI.successState(form);
            return response;
        }, function (error) {
            UI_1.UI.errorState(form);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
    }
    exports.sendForm = sendForm;
    exports.default = {
        init: init,
        send: send,
        sendForm: sendForm
    };
```

However, When I ran this, Received the "document is not defined" error". Also, I’m calling the function emailjs.send()
The function send() is defined in the code above and it says “document is undefined”. The document they are referring to is in the appendGoogleCaptcha() function which has to do with sending email.

My theory is that I need to define the window property so it knows what document of the overall page its attempting to find.
I did window.onload = function() {} but that  makes all the functions within that say “xyz does not exist”.
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Here :

```
function appendGoogleCaptcha(templatePrams) {
    var element = document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response');
    ...
}
```

And here:

```
function sendForm(serviceID, templateID, form, userID) {
    if (typeof form === 'string') {
        form = document.querySelector(form);
...
}
```

You can't do that, `document` does not exist in react native. You can replace it by reference, but if this code is not made for react-native then you will probably have more problems in the future.

Comment: Ohhh OK I see. My goal is to make a form that email is the response back to me. Is this possible and react native and if so, how do you recommend going about it?

Comment: I've never done that but this is not an unknown subject, you will have to dig a little deeper. If you have a backend then do the email send there it will be easier.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you.